# Is it required for a Calendar app to use Calendar Provider?

Tags: android, calendar, android-calendar

I'm developing an app where the user can create Events(like Calendar apps), Tasks(like Todo apps), or a Habit(like Habits tracking apps). My question is: Is it required for my app to store the events that the user creates in the [Calendar Provider](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider.html), if so, then what about tasks and habits? Do I also store them in the Calendar Provider?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it required for my app to store the events that the user creates in the Calendar Provider

No. It is an option, but you can store the events in your own database if you prefer. Or, you could give the user the choice, either for the entire app or on a per-event basis, if you like.

> if so, then what about tasks and habits? Do I also store them in the Calendar Provider?

`CalendarProvider` is only for calendar entries. My guess is that "tasks and habits" are not calendar entries, so they would go in your own database.

Comment: Minor question: what benefits will I (or users of the app)  get when storing events in Calendar Provider?

Comment: @AzzamAlsharafi: The user will be able to access those events from other calendar apps that use `CalendarProvider`. Also, frequently events in the `CalendarProvider` are synchronized with a service (e.g., Google Calendar).